# On the energies of molecular orbitals

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, electronic-configuration

I found a useful (though simplified) scheme illustrating the energies of atomic orbitals, in crescent order:

[image]

I wonder if there was an **analogous (simplified) scheme or rule for molecular orbitals**, at least for diatomic homonuclear molecules, for which the electronic state is given by the so-called *molecular term symbol*

$$\displaystyle {}^{2S+1}\!\Lambda _{\Omega ,(g/u)}^{(+/-)}$$

where

${\displaystyle S}$ is the total spin quantum number

${\displaystyle \Lambda }$ is the projection of the orbital angular momentum along the internuclear axis

${\displaystyle \Omega }$ is the projection of the total angular momentum along the internuclear axis

${\displaystyle g/u}$ indicates the symmetry or parity with respect to inversion through a centre of symmetry

${\displaystyle +/-}$ is the reflection symmetry along an arbitrary plane containing the internuclear axis

Such scheme or rule would justify for instance the following succession:

$$\sigma_g(1s)<\sigma_u(1s)<\sigma_g(2s)<\sigma_u(2s)<\pi_u(2p) <\sigma_g(2p)<\dots$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's exactly what you meant. But, how about this from https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/:

[Chemistry Fundamentals by Dr. Julie Donnelly, Dr. Nicole Lapeyrouse, and Dr. Matthew Rex](https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/chemistryfundamentals/chapter/molecular-orbital-theory/)

[image]